# Why do my Flexbox elements with set height no longer work after setting min-height to the parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am re-doing the official Tesla website just to get a bit of practice, I am aiming for the **Cybertruck** page. Here is the official look of it.

https://www.tesla.com/cybertruck

The page consists of one section that I gave a min-height of 100vh. The section contains two elements (text and a button that are inside a span) and I want to position them to the bottom-center of the section by using **Flexbox**.

**Core of the problem**

The text and button align perfectly to the center, but not to the bottom. I gave the `span` element a `flex-direction: column` and `align-items: center` which works fine, however, the elements don't align themselves to the bottom of the section when I use `justify-content: flex-end` and `height: 90%`.

Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with this problem?

```css
.main-cybertruck-section {
    background-image: url('../IMGs/cybertruck-page/cybertruck-main.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 1px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    
}

.cybertruck-utility {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end; 
    height: 90%;
    
}

.cybertruck-neon-text {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow:
      0 0 5px #fff,
      0 0 10px #fff,
      0 0 20px #fff,
      0 0 40px #0ff,
      0 0 80px #0ff,
      0 0 90px #0ff,
      0 0 100px #0ff,
      0 0 150px #0ff;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.cybertruck-order-button {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0.5em solid;
    padding: 0.01em 2em 0.01em 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body class="cybertruck">
    <section class="main-cybertruck-section">
        <span class="cybertruck-utility">
          <p class="cybertruck-neon-text intro-text">BETTER UTILITY THAN A TRUCK WITH MORE PERFORMANCE THAN A SPORTS CAR</p>
          <a class="cybertruck-order-button" href="#">ORDER NOW</a>
        </span>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your elements are indeed aligned at the flex end, but since the height of the `<span>` is as high as its child elements, you don't see that. If you would replace the `height: 90%` with an fixed height like `height: 90vh` it would actually work.

Another approach is to align the `<span>` itself within the `<section>`, as shown in the following example:

```css
.main-cybertruck-section {
    background: lightgray; /* replaced image with color, because link was broke */
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 1px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.cybertruck-utility {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.cybertruck-neon-text {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow:
      0 0 5px #fff,
      0 0 10px #fff,
      0 0 20px #fff,
      0 0 40px #0ff,
      0 0 80px #0ff,
      0 0 90px #0ff,
      0 0 100px #0ff,
      0 0 150px #0ff;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.cybertruck-order-button {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0.5em solid;
    padding: 0.01em 2em 0.01em 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body class="cybertruck">
    <section class="main-cybertruck-section">
        <span class="cybertruck-utility">
          <p class="cybertruck-neon-text intro-text">BETTER UTILITY THAN A TRUCK WITH MORE PERFORMANCE THAN A SPORTS CAR</p>
          <a class="cybertruck-order-button" href="#">ORDER NOW</a>
        </span>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question. If I was to use the second approach (aligning the span within the section) and giving the section a display: flex; what if I wanted to add more elements (an image for example) that I would want to have aligned differently? Since all elements appear at the bottom of the section now.

Comment: Depending on your scenario you could get rid of the `justify-content: flex-end` altogether and make an additional `<div>` inside the `<section>` (placed above cybertruck-utility) and give it `flex-grow: 1`. This will expand the new `<div>` and pushes down the cybertruck-utility, hence no need for the `justify-content: flex-end`. And the children (like an image) of the new `<div>` can be aligned to your needs with `display:flex` and `justify-content`.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to move the span to the end of the section then you should have the section be a flex container. Then you only need to set the flex direction to a column and set justify-content to flex-end.

```css
.main-cybertruck-section{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **.main-cybertruck-section** section you have to use height instead of min-height.I practiced it . It was work for me.

**here is  my css snippets:**

```
.main-cybertruck-section {
    background-image: url('../img/cybertruck.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
    
}

.cybertruck-utility {
    height: 90%;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end; 
    text-align:center;
}

.cybertruck-neon-text {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow:
      0 0 5px #fff,
      0 0 10px #fff,
      0 0 20px #fff,
      0 0 40px #0ff,
      0 0 80px #0ff,
      0 0 90px #0ff,
      0 0 100px #0ff,
      0 0 150px #0ff;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.cybertruck-order-button {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0.5em solid;
    padding: 0.01em 2em 0.01em 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know, I've tried that before but normal height always caused other elements on my full website to overflow to other sections, especially when resizing the browser window.

Comment: so you can use min-height . But you need to use flexbox both on container and also items . That will be fix your issue. Have a good day.